# No se puede reproducir el video - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy intentando definir un video como splash en una app `Xamarin.Android`, pero aunque el video esta reproduciéndose bien en la pc, tiene formato .mp4, y esta correctamente añadido en Resources/raw, la app me dice:

> **"No se puede reproducir el video."**

Intente añadiendo o quitando la extension .mp4 del nombre, revise el package name y la ruta generada en debug, pero no logro dar con el problema.

Codigo:

```
//Splash
                var videoPath = $"android.resource://{PackageName}/raw/sbsplash";
                VideoView VideoSplash = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.VideoViewSplash);
                //var videoPath = "android.resource://" + PackageName + Resource.raw;
                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(videoPath);
                VideoSplash.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
                VideoSplash.SetVideoURI(uri);
                VideoSplash.Start();
```

Comment: Siempre es importante revisar el Log para obtener información precisa del error, de lo contrarío pueden ser varias las causas del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente debes asegurar que tu archivo sbsplash.mp4 se encuentre dentro del directorio `/raw`, entonces esta seria la forma correcta de obtener la ruta para reproducir el video (no debes definir la extension del archivo):

```
var videoPath = "android.resource://" + Application.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.sbsplash);
```

al obtener la ruta correctamente, ahora si podrias reproducir el video:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(videoPath);
VideoSplash.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
video.SetVideoURI(uri);
video.Start();
```